# Twitter_OAuth Error : Domain=HTTP Code=410

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-oauth

I am getting an error `Domain=HTTP Code=410 "The operation couldn't be completed. (HTTP error 410.)".  in iOS application development.

This code previously worked fine but now it is throwing an error.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please put your relavent code here :)

Comment: I got the same problem, using [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone). Logging into Twitter works fine, but getting user information with `getUserInformationFor:userNameOrID` fails. It uses the `users/show/<user>.xml` twitter API.

Comment: Hi Upendra Did you get the solution?

Comment: Yes, twitter libraries are migrated.
So we need to download latest libraries and then work on that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using v1.0 of the Twitter API.
Then, the solution is to switch to version 1.1.
See: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

Overview of 1.1 API:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are using V1.0  of the twitter API. Check **Resource URL** it might be **https://api.twitter.com/1/** instead of **https://api.twitter.com/1.1/**

For further detail check **https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview**