# How to get user's info from Twitter in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am using **MGTwitterEngine** but unfortunately I am getting 401 or 403 errors.

In following methods, I tried

```
- (SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *) initOAuthWithDelegate: (NSObject *) delegate {
    if (self = (id) [super initWithDelegate: delegate]) {
        self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
        self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
        self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
    }
    return self;
}


- (SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *) initOAuthWithDelegate: (NSObject *) delegate {
    if (self = (id) [super initWithDelegate: delegate]) {
        self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
        self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
        self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
    }
    return self;
}


- (SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *) initOAuthWithDelegate: (NSObject *) delegate {
    if (self = (id) [super initWithDelegate: delegate]) {
        self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
        self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
        self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But I am un-successful here.

```
 AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            // Twitter Initialization / Login Code Goes Here
            if(!app._engine)
            {
                NSLog(@"Init the Object ");

                app._engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
                app._engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;
                app._engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
            }

            if(![app._engine isAuthorized])
            {
                NSLog(@"IN if of isAuthorized ");

                UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:app._engine delegate:self];


                if (controller)
                {
                    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

                }
            }
```

Is there any other better and easy library to get user's info of Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API has been update to api.twitter.com/1

Also Let's make all links as secure. Example :

```
self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];

self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
```

Comment: But this one I have used, I think i mentioned in question too

Comment: No use, same issue yet, 403

Comment: Do you have the aware of the Twitter api version update? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079636/twitter-oauth-error-domain-http-code-410